# how to print list of calculated area and circumferences from radius given in python

Tags: python, list, floating-point, area, radius

Hello guys i have this list of radius given 5.2, 7.0, 12.5, 7.7 and 23.5.
now i need to find the area and circumference from the radius given
but instead of making it 1 by 1 how to merge it and get the same output like below.

```
area = 3.14 * radius**2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius

print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.\
      format(radius, area, circumference))

radius = 7.0
area = 3.14 * radius**2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius

print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.\
      format(radius, area, circumference))

radius = 12.5
area = 3.14 * radius**2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius

print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.\
      format(radius, area, circumference))

radius = 7.7
area = 3.14 * radius**2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius

print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.\
      format(radius, area, circumference))

radius = 23.5
area = 3.14 * radius**2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius

print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.\
      format(radius, area, circumference))
```

output:

```
Radii: 5.2  Area: 84.9056   Circumference: 32.6560
Radii: 7.0  Area: 153.8600  Circumference: 43.9600
Radii: 12.5 Area: 490.6250  Circumference: 78.5000
Radii: 7.7  Area: 186.1706  Circumference: 48.3560
Radii: 23.5 Area: 1734.0650 Circumference: 147.5800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you want to repeat the same task over and over, it is best to turn it into a for loop. The best way to do this is to start by making a list of the data you want to change up, for your case:

```
list_of_radii = [5.2, 7.0, 12.5, 7.7, 23.5]
```

Next, you want to do something with that information. So here comes the for loop.

```
for radius in list_of_radii:
    # For loop body
```

This line will go through each radius, starting with 5.2... do something with it, and then loop to 7.0... do something with it, all the way to 23.5. Now the "body" is where you put what you want to be done. in your case:

```
area = 3.14 * radius ** 2
circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius
print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.format(radius, area, circumference))
```

This is take each radius, compute the area and circumference and then print it. So the solution to your problem looks like this:

```
list_of_radii = [5.2, 7.0, 12.5, 7.7, 23.5]

for radius in list_of_radii:
    area = 3.14 * radius ** 2
    circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius
    print('Radii: {:.1f}\tArea: {:.4f}\tCircumference: {:.4f}'.format(radius, area, circumference))
```

Comment: tq for this solution. i'm stuck at the loops method . need more practise and understanding.

Comment: @fauzan.py something you could do to help you with loops is to write or copy a pretty simple one. Then on a piece of paper, go through each line one by one writing down the updated variables and their values until you get through the entire loop so that you can see whats happening. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make a list and loop over:

```
for radius in [5.2, 7.0, 12.5, 7.7, 23.5]:
    area = 3.14 * radius**2
    ...
```

Comment: tq for this too. i'm getting the hang of it now :)